# Select a dropdown list option, and set it as a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, variables

Once a dropdown list option is selected, I would like to hold that selected option as a javascript variable.

To make this a little more complex, the variable should be held inside the page's main Ajax coding, so it is not lost when different Ajax content is loaded.

Here's my wonderfully basic form code:

```
<form name="searchLocations" method="POST">
        <select name="locationName">
            <?php 
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT locationName FROM tbl_locations ORDER BY locationName ASC");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            echo "<option value=\"owner1\">" . $row['locationName'] . "</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <button onclick="loadXMLDoc(indexSearchingSubmit);" id="searchingSubmit">Search</button>
    </form>
```

and here is my main ajax code, where the form dropdown variable should be held so it can be used later:

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    var everyone = document.getElementById('everyone'),
        searching = document.getElementById('searching'),
        searchingSubmit = document.getElementById('searchingSubmit');

    everyone.onclick = function() {
        loadXMLDoc('indexEveryone');
        everyone.className = 'filterOptionActive';
        searching.className = 'filterOption';
    }

    searching.onclick = function() {
        loadXMLDoc('indexSearching');        
        searching.className = 'filterOptionActive';
        everyone.className = 'filterOption';
    }

     searchingSubmit.onclick = function() {
        loadXMLDoc('indexSearchingSubmit');  
    }

    function loadXMLDoc(pageName)
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            document.getElementById("leftCont").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
          }

        function get_query(){
          var url = location.href;
          var qs = url.substring(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
          for(var i = 0, result = {}; i < qs.length; i++){
            qs[i] = qs[i].split('=');
            result[qs[i][0]] = decodeURIComponent(qs[i][1]);
          }
          return result;
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","../browse/" + pageName + ".php?user=" + get_query()['user'],true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
}
</script>
<!-- ends ajax script -->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Using jQuery:
    $('[name="locationName"]').change(function() {
      YOUR_VAR = $(this).attr('value');
    });


Not using jQuery- 
Add onChange() to your SELECT element, also added id attribute.
Add javascript onchange handler function, which just retrieves the selected value and sets your var

    <select name="locationName" onChange="setSelected()" id="locationSelect">

    function setSelected(){
      var myselect= document.getElementById("locationSelect");
      YOUR_VAR = myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex].value;
    }
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work, but maybe I'm just not understanding. I just added 3 elements to my coding, but now think I should be adding just 1. Should I add the top Jquery content into my ajax code and the value will be held once a user clicks a dropdown option?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear.  The first chunk of code is using jQuery to hook into the select form change().   I then noticed you were not using jQuery elsewhere, so added the second example where I tried to cobble together an example that does not use jQuery.  In this example you needed to make a couple small changes to your html Select element, as well as adding the javascript function that gets fired from the call to onChange().

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, I used the first example but it didn't seem to work. I added the function into my ajax script so it could be held there. I try to print it out once the page changes but it doesn't work. Does the variable need to be global or something?

Comment: Your variable to hold the result would need to be in a global scope.

Comment: My knowledge is very basic, can you advise me how to do that?

Comment: Just define your variable in your main javascript code (not within a specific function).   Here's a quick link to explain better than I am doing:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx